# LazyLoading is turned off. Child objects still recursively loaded when .Include() is used.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

In our web-app we're using Facade pattern. This leads us to make use of Automapper to convert between object layers DAL <-> DTO <-> ViewModels.

I have LazyLoading disabled, and it has taken effect for the most part.
However some nested objects are included without explicitly adding them in an ".include" statement.

### Example:

```
public class Parent {
    public Guid? Child1Id{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Child1Id")]
    public Child1 Child1 { get; set; }
}

public class Child1 {
    public Guid? Child2Id{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Child2Id")]
    public Child2 Child2 { get; set; }
}

public class Child2 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now any attempt to retrieve the Parent and Child1; will also return Child2
as shown:

```
var Parent = RepositoryReference.DbContext
                .Parents
                .Include(p => p.Child1);
```

when drilling into the parent object, Child2 is retrieved as shown

```
Parent.Child1.Child2 != null
```

Please note Child2 is not Virtual.

What further actions can I take to ignore nested children of objects I explicitly include?

Thanks

Comment: I think you call child2 in some other place, please check with SQL profiler to find when child2 is calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all be sure to configure your context to turn off Lazy loading as below:

```
public DbContext()
    : base("Name = ConntectionName")
{
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

As @MahdiFarhani stated another reason can be that you load Child2 *with same id* in the same scope. Imagine following scenario:

```
var child2Id = ......;
Child2 child2 = RepositoryReference
    .DbContext
    .Child2s
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == child2Id);

Parent Parent = RepositoryReference
    .DbContext
    .Parents
    .Include(p => p.Child1);
```

If **parent.Child1.Child2** is equal to **child2Id** in above scenario, then they are automatically related and *parent.Child1.Child2* is not null anymore. So if this is true for you, be sure to explicitly set parent.Child1.Child2 to null or use **AsNoTracking()** when retrieving Child2:

```
Child2 child2 = RepositoryReference
    .DbContext
    .Child2s
    .AsNoTracking() // Add this line to not keep Child2 in context
    .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == child2Id);
```